# Ctrl+z and fg with SSH - why doesn't it work?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm connecting to a VPS using SSH client on Android (JuiceSSH). I run a program, and then send it to background using Ctrl+Z. Then, why when I connect to this VPS using Bitvise SSH on my PC (the Android connection is still open), when I type "fg", there are no jobs?

How can I interact with the same instance of a program, but in another SSH client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs exist on their parent shell only.
Use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/).

Comment: This answer is correct, but needs to be expanded to be helpful to someone who is `rather new to Linux`